# Cannot echo IF () into a text block I am creating in a batch file

Tags: cmd

Am creating a batch file within a batch file and wanted to use the structure

```
(
echo line 1
…
) > test1.bat
```

This all worked good until I tried putting in an if statement.  The ending ")" of the if terminated the text block.  I even tried

```
set "_ascii=)"
echo %_ascii%
```

but it was expanded to ")" when echoed and the text block terminated. I don't see how to write the ")" to the batch file I am trying to create.

Sample code:  test.bat

```
(
echo set "VAR=1"
echo goto SkipOverFunctions
echo :foo
echo if %%VAR%% EQU 1 (
echo echo var is 1
echo exit /B 0
echo )
echo exit /B 1
echo :SkipOverFunctions
echo call foo
) > test1.bat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the literal parenthesis with `^` so it isn't parsed as the block terminator :

```
(
    echo line1
    echo (line2^)
    echo line3
) > output
```

An alternative would be to use the `>>` "append" redirection :

```
echo line1 > output
echo (line2) >> output
echo line3 >> output
```

Comment: the above works fine when parsing parenthesis in a block but I cannot get that escape too work with angle brackets as in (
^<config^>
^</config^>
) > test.xml  Going to put this on a separate question when I get a chance

Comment: @JosephStateson it's supposed to work : `echo >foo` writes to a file while `echo ^>foo` displays `>foo`. In general it is useful for the following characters: `& \ < > ^ |`. More infos [there](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: I posted a better example of the problem. I did look at a lot of previous solutions but all I saw that worked used the echo mechanism https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733164/is-way-to-escape-angle-brackets-in-a-text-block-directed-to-a-file