# Is way to escape angle brackets in a text block directed to a file?

Tags: cmd

Using a bash script as a working example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\
<global_preferences>
... 
</global_preferences>" >> global_prefs.xml
```

I tried the following that (IMHO) should have worked but didn't

```
(
^<config^>
^</config^>
) > test.xml
```

The following does work but is a PITA as the xml file is long

```
echo ^<config^> > test.xml
echo ^</config^> >> test.xml
```

Comment: Aren't you simply missing your `echo`s? `(\n echo ^<config^>\n echo ^<config^>\n) > test.xml` works for me (with linefeeds were I wrote `\n`)

Comment: Also I strongly suggest you use template files which you'd use as a base for your generated files and in which you would replace the variable values. Writing whole files from `cmd` is the kind of PITA that makes you forget to write a command every line ;)

Comment: you are correct.  for some reason thought the "echo" would go into the file.  poking around it seems template files are part of powershell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Windows_commands  I am trying to duplicate a bash script that works on ubuntu and want same behavior in windows 10

Comment: You can treat any file as a template file, I was thinking about something like a `global_prefs.xml.template` with content like `<config><pref1>${pref1}</pref1><pref2>${pref2}</pref2><pref3>always the same</pref3></config>` which you'd first copy to `global_prefs.xml` then replace in that file `${pref1}` and `${pref2}` with their desired value. Easier to write as much of the file content in a file and just the script only for data that needs decision/processing